# JS - document.getelementbysrc?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get an element from the value of the "src" attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no DOM method to filter elements by attributes. You need to go through all the elements of a particular tag and filter out those with a matching `src` value:

```
function getElementsBySrc(srcValue) {
  var nodes = [];
  var e = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

  for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    if (e[i].hasAttribute('src') && e[i].getAttribute('src') == srcValue) {
      nodes.push(e[i]);
    }
  }

  return nodes;
}
```

The `nodes` array will contain all the `img` elements with a `src` attribute that has a value `image.png`.

---

**UPDATE:**

Further to the comment below, keep in mind that there might be more than one element with the same `src` value. That is why the function above returns an array.

You can use the [`element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute) method to change the value of an attribute:

```
var n = getElementsBySrc('old-image.png');

for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
  n[i].setAttribute('src', 'new-image.png');
}
```

Comment: would it then be possible to change the value of it? (the img src attribute)

Comment: In this case i know the image is only going to appear once, So that did it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found some code when google:

```
function getElementsByAttribute(oElm, strTagName, strAttributeName, strAttributeValue){
    var arrElements = (strTagName == "*" && oElm.all)? oElm.all : oElm.getElementsByTagName(strTagName);
    var arrReturnElements = new Array();
    var oAttributeValue = (typeof strAttributeValue != "undefined")? new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + strAttributeValue + "(\\s|$)", "i") : null;
    var oCurrent;
    var oAttribute;
    for(var i=0; i<arrElements.length; i++){
        oCurrent = arrElements[i];
        oAttribute = oCurrent.getAttribute && oCurrent.getAttribute(strAttributeName);
        if(typeof oAttribute == "string" && oAttribute.length > 0){
            if(typeof strAttributeValue == "undefined" || (oAttributeValue && oAttributeValue.test(oAttribute))){
                arrReturnElements.push(oCurrent);
            }
        }
    }
    return arrReturnElements;
}
```

Source: http://snipplr.com/view/1853/get-elements-by-attribute/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK (As Far As I Know) there is no native method to get the an element from the value of the **src** attribute. But using a JavaScript library you can achieve this in one line.

If you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you can get the element writing the following code:

```
var elem = $('[src="path/to/something.xyz"]');
```

More documentation about this previous code in the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: I think you forgot the wildcard in the selector

Comment: Using jQuery you can do `var elem = $('[src]');`